# In JS how to pass Array Parameter to GAS and then retrieve result

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, web-applications

In my Google Sheet I have a list of books with their details. The user inserts the title he's looking for, jQuery passes the title to a function in GAS and then it returns the matches (found books) to the JS.

Here my code.

**HTML**

```
<form id="formD">
  <input type="text" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Math">
  <button id="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
$("#submit").click(function()
{
  var data = [];
  data.push($("#title").val()); //title the user is looking for
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).find(data);
});

function onSuccess(a)
{
    alert(a); //example
}
```

**GAS**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index')
    .evaluate()
    .addMetaTag('viewport', 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1');
}

function find(data) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXX").getSheetByName("XXX");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A:G");
  var values = range.getValues();

  var result = [];

  var title = data[0];

  for(i=0; i < values.length; i++){
    if(values[i][0] != "")
    {  
       if(values[i][2].includes(title))
         result.push(values[i]);
    }
  }

  return result
}
```

I don't know how to parse and use the array I pass to GAS. When the button "search" is clicked, the page is reloaded and the value appended to the URL.

Comment: Welcome to [so].  What do you mean by `When the button "search" is clicked, the page is reloaded and the value appended to the URL.`? Please bear in mind that questions on this site should be specific, meaning, only one question / issue by post. Also question looking for help on fixing code should include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

#### Try it this way

```
function find(data) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("XXX").getSheetByName("XXX");
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:G" + sheet.getLastRow());
  var values = range.getValues();
  var result = [];
  var title = data;
  for (let i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0] != "") {
      if (values[i][2].includes(title))
        result.push(values[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

function onSuccess(a) {
    alert(a.join('\n')); //example
}
```

js:

#### No need for data to be an array

```
$("#submit").click(function() {
  var data = $("#title").val(); 
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSuccess).find(data);
});
```

[client to server communications](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)

Comment: @Rubén maybe not?

Comment: The problem is that when clicking the button it reloads the page. I declared "data" as an array because actually there are other "filters".

Comment: You are right... sorry.

Comment: @gio-remo at this point it doesn't make sense to me

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to the problem that when clicking the button the page reloads.

```
$("#sumbit").click(function(){

}
```

This piece of code was outside $(document).ready(function(){}).